# Where I could find the source code for the built in wallpaper app/activity in Android.

Tags: android, wallpaper

If you long press the Android luncher and then you pressed Wallpapers an app/activity is opened and you could select the wallpaper (it have a gallery view at the bottom). Where I could find the source code for this app/activity in the Android source code (can you point me to the file location or the github url for the app/activity specific path).

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/WallpaperChooserDialogFragment.java should be the thing that lets you choose static wallpapers

Comment: Thanks, can you add it as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wallpaper chooser for images should be the following part of the launcher

[`/packages/apps/Launcher2/../WallpaperChooserDialogFragment.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/master/src/com/android/launcher2/WallpaperChooserDialogFragment.java)

There are also live wallpaper related packages, for example this could be the chooser for live wallpapers.

[`/packages/wallpapers/LivePicker`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/LivePicker/+/master/)